# Constructor implementation is missing

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to inject a service to my component and I think I have written everything correctly but it gives me an error saying `Constructor implementation is missing`.

My component is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Lists} from "./lists";
import {ListsService} from "./lists.service";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-lists',
  templateUrl: './lists.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lists.component.css']
})
export class ListsComponent implements OnInit {

  lists: Lists[] = [];
  constructor(private listService: ListsService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lists = this.listService.getItems();
  }

}
```

My service:

```
import {Lists} from "./lists";
export class ListsService {
  private lists: Lists[] = [];

  addLists(list: Lists){
    this.lists.push(list);
    console.log(`You added ${list}`)
  }

  getItems(){
    return this.lists;
  }
}
```

and my template is:

```
<app-lists-edit></app-lists-edit>
<app-lists-row *ngFor="let list of lists" [item]="list"></app-lists-row>
```

Anything that I have done here is a mistake. I even entered the service in providers in `ngModule`.

And other errors are:

```
ERROR in C:/Sites/Angular2main/todolist/src/app/lists/lists.ts (2,15): A parameter property is only allowed in a constructor implementation.

ERROR in C:/Sites/Angular2main/todolist/src/app/lists/lists.ts (3,15): A parameter property is only allowed in a constructor implementation.

ERROR in C:/Sites/Angular2main/todolist/src/app/lists/lists.ts (4,15): A parameter property is only allowed in a constructor implementation.

ERROR in C:/Sites/Angular2main/todolist/src/app/lists/lists.ts (4,15): A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.
```

Well my mistake was in my model

```
export class Lists {
  constructor(private title: string, private description: string, private completed: boolean)
}
```

I didn't put curly brackets after my constructor.

Comment: Try adding a `contructor() {}` to your service and let me know.

Comment: Did you provide `ListsService` anywhere?

Comment: Well its working fine.. Thanks a loads but why adding constructor in the service helping me here.If you could explain that then it would be wonders for me..Anyways thank you @Christopher

Comment: No worries, I'll write an answer so you can accept it (for other people to see) :-)

Comment: You should posts the content of your `lists.ts` file. The issue probably lies there. There should be no need to add a `constructor` to the `ListsService`

Comment: That's a fair point, the error message was clear but the cause was not.

Comment: Well PierreDuc You are right that i made a simple mistake in the list.ts. I corrected that it works fine..Thanks though.

Comment: @Mannish care to share the mistake for future readers?

Comment: I did @PierreDuc. Actually I created that class way before implementing it in this component. I even used in a different component but didnt give any errors at first. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error message states that you need a constructor in your service.

Therefore add a `contructor() {}` in your `ListsService`.

Although the cause of your problem is not clear, you may need to show us the contents of your `lists.ts` as has stated PierreDuc in order to understand the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Also such error could appear if you provide bad type for one of constructor's argument.
[image]

Study them and fix to get rid of this error.
[image]